# Does Facebook have a webhook that an app can subscribe to to detect when a Facebook event is added to a page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks, facebook-events, facebook-webhooks

Does Facebook have a webhook that an app can subscribe to to detect when a [Facebook event](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/event) is added to a page? Or do apps that are interested in this information just have to repeatedly poll /[page-id]?fields=events ?

Answer (score 0):

For example if you have a page that creates some event, as long as you subscribe to **feeds**, *Facebook Realtime API* will send you json payload that looks similar to this:

```
{
"entry": [
    {
        "changes": [
            {
                "field": "feed",
                "value": {
                    "story": "Some page added an event.",
                    "item": "event",
                    "event_id": "2277580782468248",
                    "post_id": "1442694315844896_2277580782468248",
                    "verb": "add",
                    "created_time": 1511651353,
                    "message": "test event"
                }
            }
        ],
        "id": "1442694315844895",
        "time": 1511651355
    }
],
"object": "page"
```

}

Then you probably would like to pull the Graph API for additional informations about your *event_id*

Comment: I'm subscribed to feeds, and the API does send me an appropriate JSON payload if a page *shares* one of its events to its page -- i.e., any posts which appear as "[Page Name] shared their event." However, I'm not getting anything when the event is simply created by the page -- i.e. I'm not getting any payloads for posts which appear as "[Page Name] added an event."

Answer (score 0):

The product you are trying to find is Facebook Webhooks https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/. It allows you to subscribe to changes on the Facebook page and get alert only when change occures. You don't need to have regular calls with Graph API to see whether there are changes.

First you need to create facebook app, and then to add webhooks on that Facebook app. Next step is to subscribe that webhook to page you want and select "feed" as subscription. You will be informed about any change on your page.

Comment: I'm aware that the webhooks exist, but I didn't see any that I can subscribe to to be informed when a Facebook event is added to a page. I looked pretty hard and wasn't able to find one that provides this information. My question was about whether such a webhook exists, and if so, which one it is.

Comment: I have updated answer. It is ofering you all you need. You just need to create facebook app, then add webhooks on that app, subscribe app to facebook page, and you will get info about all updates.